# Resolving AR.js Errors in Angular Project Using A-Frame for Marker-based AR

Tags: angular, typescript, npm, aframe, ar.js

How can I resolve the errors that are being thrown in my Angular project when using AR.js with A-Frame?

I am attempting to incorporate AR.js into my Angular project, specifically using Marker-based AR with A-Frame. To start, I have installed A-Frame via NPM and imported it into my 'pollyfills.ts' file using the statement 'import aframe'.

Next, I downloaded the JavaScript file from the documentation using the following link: "https://raw.githack.com/AR-js-org/AR.js/master/aframe/build/aframe-ar.js". In order for it to work properly, I am loading it within Angular specifically in the 'ngOnInit' method using the code:

```
ngOnInit(): void {
    const ar= require('../../assets/ar_aframe.js');
}
```

, which seems to be functioning correctly. This means that the webcam is being loaded, and the objects are being recognized. This is the HTML-Code:

```
<a-scene arjs="sourceType: webcam; detectionMode: mono_and_matrix; matrixCodeType: 3x3;" renderer="precision: medium;"
    vr-mode-ui="enabled: false" cursor="fuse: true;rayOrigin: mouse">
    <a-entity camera raycaster="objects: .clickable">
      <a-marker type="barcode" value="1" size="0.7">
        <a-box  position="0 0 0"
          material="opacity: 0.9; side: double;color:white;" class="clickable" width="2" height="2" depth="2"
          (click)="test($event,1)" geometry="primitive: box" aabb-collider>
        </a-box>
      </a-marker>
    </a-entity>
  </a-scene>
```

However, I am encountering several errors in the console, which appear to be originating from AR.js. I have also attempted to include an older version of AR.js, but the same problem persists. During the installation of A-Frame via NPM, I made sure to use version 1.3.0.

```
ERROR TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'addEventListener')
    at NewSystem.init (ar_aframe.js:1:1663386)
    at module.exports.System (aframe-master.js:28677:8)
    at new NewSystem (aframe-master.js:28775:12)
    at AScene.initSystem (aframe-master.js:27229:26)
    at module.exports.registerSystem (aframe-master.js:28785:15)
    at ar_aframe.js:1:1660640
    at ar_aframe.js:1:1664865
    at ar_aframe.js:1:1664871
    at ar_aframe.js:1:81
    at 4572 (ar_aframe.js:1:289)
```

and 3 of that one:

```
ar_aframe.js:1 Assertion failed: console.assert
b   @   ar_aframe.js:1
(anonymous) @   ar_aframe.js:1
```

How can I go about resolving these errors? It seems as though they are related to the AR.js library.